# Using ROME to search RSS feeds

Tags: java, rss, rome

I'm using ROME to read and combine RSS feeds (caching is done with EhCache) in a Java environment. Is there functionality built in to the Rome API that allows you to search the contents of a feed (or a combination of different feeds) and then combine the ones that meet a specific search criteria?

I'm thinking of implementing that myself by reading the feed contents and searching using a Regex or whatever, but would rather use built-in API logic if it's available (I've looked at the Rome tutorials here:

http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javawsxml/Rome05TutorialFeedAggregator

...but couldn't find anything specifically feed-search-related).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain there is not built in search capability.

Comment: I thought there probably wasn't, but thanks for the confirmation: I've done it manually instead (mapping the getContent() value of my SyndContent object to a bean property and then taking it from there).

Comment: You might be able to use Lucene to do indepth text based searches if you want more robust searching capabilities.

http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/